# How to use useEffect in a table to fetch data from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a table which looks like this:

```
    Id  number of books
    1       XX
    2       ...
    3       ...
   ...      ...
```

The number of books would be fetched from backend using useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Id) {
      dispatch(
        getBookNumbers({
        Id: Id,
        })
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

How can I write useEffect functions to fetch different numbers through different Ids?
Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: Where is the `Id` coming from?  If you are keeping track of `Id` in a state variable, you can add it to the dependency array (the array at the end of the `useEffect`), and the effect will run every time the `Id` changes, with that `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `Id` variable as a state variable. Second array param of `UseEffect`, will create it sensitive on those variables, which means it will trigger on their change. So your useEffect can be like this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   if !Id return;
   // do my logic
},[Id])
```

React has a clear documentation, It will help you understand well.

Comment: Thanks so much, but my Id is an array and does not change at all. So I am thinking is there a way to combine useEffect and map function?

Comment: If you mean you want to get multiple books details after component mount, you can use ```Promise.All``` and ```Map``` to fetch them concurrent (But in different independent requests). Also it depends the fetcher too, may it can fetch multiple once.